# File found in IntelliJ but not in built jar

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am running some code through a compiler, and I have to query which Operating System the user is using to call the appropriate binary.  The code works, and calls the binary in IntelliJ, but when I build a jar file with gradle, I get a file not found exception (the binary) on the line that corresponds to val tempBinaryCopy.

```
 fun assemble(file: String) {

    val currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir")

    val binary = when {
        System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Linux") -> javaClass.classLoader.getResource("osx_linux").file
        System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac") -> javaClass.classLoader.getResource("osx_mac").file
        else ->javaClass.classLoader.getResource("osx_win.exe").file
    }

    val binaryFile = File(binary).name
    val assemblyFile = File(file).name

    val tempBinaryCopy = File(binary).copyTo(File(currentDirectory, binaryFile), true)
    val tempAssemblyCopy = File(file).copyTo(File(currentDirectory, assemblyFile), true)

    tempAssemblyCopy.deleteOnExit()
    tempBinaryCopy.deleteOnExit()

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(tempBinaryCopy.toPath(), setOf(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE))
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf(tempBinaryCopy.absolutePath, tempAssemblyCopy.absolutePath, "-v"))
    process.inputStream.bufferedReader().readLines().forEach { println(it) }
}
```

The exception

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.io.NoSuchFileException: file:/Users/dross/Desktop/OS.jar!/osx_mac: The source file doesn't exist.
at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:179)
at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:177)
at com.max.power.os.assembler.ProvidedAssembler.assemble(ProvidedAssembler.kt:22)
```

I have also tried a replace on the line in question to remove the ! and the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javaClass.classLoader.getResource("osx_linux")` gives you an instance of `URL`, `URL.file` gives you the file part of the `URL`. This might work as long as the file is not packaged in a JAR, but as you can see fails in case the file is packed into a JAR. You should probably instead use `getResourceAsStream` and the copy the `InputStream` you receive to the destination where you want to have it.